# Retail POS return transaction double tax inclusion

Tags: c#, transactions, return, axapta, microsoft-dynamics

I want to customize the method that fetches transaction data from `HQ` while we return a transaction from `POS`.

Is it allowed or is it the part of some `DLL` that we do not have code available in retail `SDK` of ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  resolved the issue. 
I subtracted the tax amount from the actual amount if the transaction was a return transaction and it was fetched from HQ.
It worked for me.